# SOAP - don't know what my endpoint URL is

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, soap, soapui

I hope this problem is extremely simple and it's just me being an idiot. I am new to SOAP and am attempting to set up a SOAP WebService (using Java and Spring) and then using the tool SoapUI I attempt to send a SOAP request to my Web service. However I always get 404 Not Found errors when I submit my request. I suspect / hope that I have just set my Endpoint incorrectly in SoapUI, but I don't know what value I should be putting there. Can anyone help?

These are the steps I have taken to setup my WebApp with SOAP support:

1) I am using an existing WebApp (which has existing REST Web Services) running in Spring Tool Suite (which is based on Eclipse) and using Jetty. In my web.xml file I added a new SOAP Web Service:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SOAPWebService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/SOAP/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>SOAPWebService</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

2) I created a new class "ProjectSearchEndpoint" which has an annotation of @Endpoint. The payload root = @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://FOO.FOO/foo", localPart = "ProjectRequest")

3) I added the DSD to the WEB-INF of my WebApp: ws-project.xsd

4) I created a servlet XML file called: SOAPWebService-servlet.xml which references the DSD

```
<bean id="projectSearch" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
  <property name="schema" ref="schema"/>
  <property name="portTypeName" value="ProjectSearch"/>
</bean>

<bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/ws-project.xsd"/>
</bean>
```

**NOTE:** the endpoint code and DSD come from the blog:
http://javaclue.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/soap-web-service-using-spring-ws-20.html I edited the namespace to make it "http://FOO.FOO/foo" but apart from that the code is the same although I have added System.out lines to show when the object is constructed (it is) and when the "searchProjects" method is invoked (it never is).

I can start my webApp successfully and if in my browser I navigate to the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ws/SOAP/projectSearch.wsdl
```

I get to see the WSDL. All good so far.

When I use SoapUI I create a new project and pass in the WSDL. SoapUI seems happy. I ask for a request and SoapUI creates a Soap Envelope with my ProjectRequest in it. Everything is going very well! However to submit this request SoapUI wants an Endpoint. I think my endpoint is:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ws/SOAP/
```

but this just returns a 404 not found. Trying other combinations such as

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ws/SOAP/projectSearch
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ws/SOAP/projectSearch?wsdl
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ws/SOAP/ProjectRequest
```

all result in 404. What is my endpoint? What value should I be putting into SoapUI?

**Update 1**

For clarity this is what I am doing in soapUI

Having started soapUI, I create a "new soapUI Project". The name is A1. The Initial WSDL is:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ws/SOAP/projectSearch.wsdl
```

also "Create Requests" is ticked in the dialog box.

I click OK and it creates a ProjectSearchSoap11 (with an icon of a green I next to it) with a single Project underneath it (icon of red arrows) and under that "Request1" (icon the word SOAP). I right-click Request1 and select "Show Request Editor". This displays a window with a SOAP envelope and my namespace and ProjectRequest. This all looks good.

I now want to click "Submit request to sepecified Endpoint URL" (green arrow at top-left) but this is greyed-out until I specify an endpoint (to the right). I click on the endpoints drop-down and select "edit-current". A dialog appears. I enter:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ws/SOAP/
```

and click ok. Now the run icon is enabled (green). Clicking this icon then results in a "response" window appearing, which is blank, but the raw data is:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

I am guessing that the endpoint I am choosing is wrong. Can you confirm that this is the wrong format or I'm missing a suffix of some kind. If you think it's correct then it must be my setup on the web application that is at fault.

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

When you create the soapui testrequest it should populate the endpoint field for you.

You can also run the 'sample requests' under the green 'I' icon, at least to test your endpoint. I don't recommend editing these to use as your actual tests, but I think that many people do use SoapUI that way.

What do you mean by 'I ask for a request'?  You should be able to right click the test request two levels under the green 'I' and select add to testcase.  There are a couple dialogs after that where you can take the defaults.  It will create a Junit type structure: a test suite and a test case.  Under that are test steps which you can execute by themselves or as part of the suite or testcase.

EDIT 1:

To me that doesn't sound normal.  Unfortunately, I haven't written anything but simple demo services, though...

Comment: I'll update the question to explain what I am doing in soapUI. It's too long to explain in this comment box.